# Team Project resource in different location that Team Services account

Tags: azure, azure-devops, team-project

I've create Team Project and with it also Team Services Account using Azure portal.

I don't know how it happened, but not Team Project resource is in different location than Team Services Account resource. I can see it in Azure Portal -> All Resources.

**1. Which location is actually used?** I want optimal connectivity for the team portal and repositories.

**2. Can I move team project to different location?** I wanted to delete/recreate it, but I don't see delete option for team project in the azure portal. I can only delete entire resource group.

Comment: Do you mean the VSTS region or Azure Active Directory? VSTS in Azure portal only has the connection for AAD, and you can change the connection. More details about AAD, you can refer https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/manage-organization-access-for-your-account-vs.

Comment: How do you know team project is in the different location than team services account? Regarding delete team project, you can delete it in your VSTS admin page.

Comment: There are two resources created in azure: Team Project and Team Services Account. Each resource has it's location

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the project from All resources in Azure Portal:
[image]

And then sign in the created VSTS account, click settings button and then navigate to "Overview" panel to delete the project in VSTS:
[image]

Comment: ehm, are you sure you posted this answer to correct question?

Comment: @Liero I'm answering your second quesion:  I wanted to delete/recreate it, but I don't see delete option for team project in the azure portal. I can only delete entire resource group.